# selenium webdriver - unable to select dropdown in grid

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

please help me with this issues, in our web application most of the pages having dropdown’s in grid. While automating such process, it simply clicks the td (cell of the grid) and spontaneously the dropdown displayed and get hide. Because if its getting hide immediate we can’t perform next operation. How can we deal with such issues?  So that we can’t proceed further.

I just tried with following functions in selenium webdriver.am using java(selenium version 2.52.0)
Click
Clickandhold
Tab keys
Double click 
Enter keys

Please advice? Thanks in advance.

[Action on click.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pED4V.png)
[After Click drop down get's disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PENd6.png)

Comment: Have you tried hover webdriver action? it should work.

Comment: thanks manu for the reply, did you mean to perform hover action in the cell, if am using hover, how can i enable that dropdown in the cell.

Comment: Ideally hovering over the cell should make the element visible so that actions can be performed on it.

Comment: hi manu thanks a lot it worked like a charm, i just passed Enter with focus.